# Changing the whole installer background with image(Not slideshow)

Tags: image, background, inno-setup, pascalscript

### How do I fill the Setup background with a picture like in the image with inno setup.

[image: Picture is only for hint.]

**Picture is only for hint.**

**I don't want to make slideshow.I want to change the setup background not desktop background which will show some slideshow.**

**Please see the picture!**

I think I need to do something in the `[Code]` section!

*Thanks*.

Comment: @TLama Can u help me in this particular problem?

Comment: @ Martin Prikryl  No i don't want to make slideshow, I want to change the skin of the setup.

Comment: Sure, but a still image is a subset of a slideshow, right?

Comment: @ Martin Prikryl I want only one image that will be shown in every page-`Wpselecttask`,`wpwelcomepage` etc

Comment: Anybody know how to do this?

Comment: Did answer below (Graphical Installer) worked fine for you?

Comment: @Slappy Yes, but it's not free!

Answer (score 2):

Use [graphical installer](http://www.graphical-installer.com/joomla/) to change the whole installer skin with a picture.

Comment: Did you have a time to try Graphical Installer (from post above) ? How much do you like it?